# ¿Cómo obtener último registro y sus datos sin subconsultas en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, subconsultas

Quiero saber si existe alguna forma más óptima de obtener el último registro de una tabla mediante una subconsulta y luego relacionarla con otra para obtener los datos relacionados al último registro obtenido en la primer consulta.

¿Se puede hacer lo siguiente en una sola consulta?

Ejemplo de consulta:

```
SELECT EMAIL.CLIENTEID
    ,EMAIL.EMAIL
FROM CLIENTESEMAILS email
    ,(
        SELECT ce.clienteid
            ,max(CE.CLIENTEEMAILID) AS maximo
        FROM CLIENTESEMAILS ce
        WHERE CE.ESTADO = 'A'
            AND CE.CLIENTEID IN (id del cliente)
        GROUP BY ce.clienteid
        ) maximo
WHERE EMAIL.CLIENTEEMAILID = maximo.maximo;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

La forma más eficiente de hacer la consulta es evitando hacer el join adicional, y más bien usando la función ventana `row_number()` para identificar los registros más recientes por `clienteid`:

```
select clienteid,
       email
  from (select clienteid,
               email,
               row_number() over (partition by clienteid
                                      order by clienteemailid desc) as rn
          from clientesemails
         where estado = 'A'
           and clienteid in (id del cliente))
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo has escrito:

```
select  email.CLIENTEID,
        email.EMAIL
        from CLIENTESEMAILS email
        INNER JOIN (select  ce.clienteid,
                            max (CE.CLIENTEEMAILID) as maximo
                            from CLIENTESEMAILS ce
                            where CE.ESTADO = 'A'
                            and CE.CLIENTEID in ( id del cliente)
                            GROUP BY ce.clienteid
        ) maximo
        ON EMAIL.CLIENTEEMAILID = maximo.maximo;
```

Aquí usamos la subconsulta como tabla, y con un `INNER JOIN` lo que hacemos es traer el `EMAIL` por cada `CLIENTEID` que corresponda al máximo  `CLIENTEEMAILID`  que en caso de ser un autonumérico podría decirse que es el último ingresado.

Comment: No entiendo ni la consulta del usuario ni tu respuesta. cual es el punto de hacer una subconsulta que va a devolver un solo registro en oracle, cuando alcanza con igualarlo en el where?

Comment: Entiendo que el OP tiene múltiples `CLIENTESEMAILS` por `CLIENTEID` pero lo que busca es obtener el último `EMAIL` ingresado en cada caso.

Comment: ok.. vale.. igual me sobra una coma, una condicion de join o que sea un join explicito.

Answer (score 0):

Si yo entendí bien tu consulta, tienes un maximoid (CLIENTEEMAILID)y en otra tabla estas buscando los datos relacionados a eso. Entonces tu consulta es mucho mas simple.

Oracle te permite ubicar un max si hacer una agrupación, por lo tanto, alcanza con tener una consulta que haga lo siguiente:

```
select
   EMAIL.CLIENTEID,
   EMAIL.EMAIL
from
   CLIENTESEMAILS email
WHERE
   EMAIL.CLIENTEEMAILID = 
      (SELECT MAX(CLIENTEEMAILID) FROM CLIENTESEMAILS 
       WHERE
          ESTADO = 'A'
       AND
          CLIENTEID = ( id del cliente)
      )
```

Igual no termino de comprender la pregunta, y puede que la respuesta de Patricio en este caso sea mas correcta